# How to intercept the editing in source editor of Android Studio and take action as GitHub Copilot?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-plugin, github-copilot

Plugins for Android Studio like GitHub Copilot can provide instant help to developer based on the editing.

How can I create a plugin for Android Studio to intercept user's input and take action (including providing instant hints) based on the input? Where can I find a guide on that?

Is it supported by https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/modifying-psi.html#creating-the-new-psi?